# Фон для изображения с альфа каналом

Tags: php, изображения

Имеется изображение с альфа каналом, оно используется как маска: на изображении три кубика, два зеленого цвета, а третий имеет прозрачность, под эту картинку я подкладываю прямоугольник нужного цвета и получаю таким образом изображения с разным цветом третьего кубика.
Нужно как-то сделать чтобы можно было получать одно изображение с заданным цветом в том месте где используется маска .. иначе говоря нужно сделать заполнение альфа канала заданным цветом